# Spark2 Dataframe/RDD process in groups

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table stored in Hive called ExampleData:

```
+--------+-----+---|
|Site_ID |Time |Age|
+--------+-----+---|
|1       |10:00| 20|
|1       |11:00| 21|
|2       |10:00| 24|
|2       |11:00| 24|
|2       |12:00| 20|
|3       |11:00| 24|
+--------+-----+---+
```

I need to be able to process the data by Site. Unfortunately partitioning it by Site doesn't work (there are over 100k sites, all with fairly small amounts of data).

For each site, I need to select the Time column and Age column separately, and use this to feed into a function (which ideally I want to run on the executors, not the driver)

I've got a stub of how I think I want it to work, but this solution would only run on the driver, so it's very slow. I need to find a way of writing it so it will run an executor level:

```
// fetch a list of distinct sites and return them to the driver 
//(if you don't, you won't be able to loop around them as they're not on the executors)
val distinctSites = spark.sql("SELECT site_id FROM ExampleData GROUP BY site_id LIMIT 10")
.collect

val allSiteData = spark.sql("SELECT site_id, time, age FROM ExampleData")

distinctSites.foreach(row => {
    allSiteData.filter("site_id = " + row.get(0))
    val times = allSiteData.select("time").collect()
    val ages = allSiteData.select("ages").collect()
    processTimesAndAges(times, ages)
})

def processTimesAndAges(times: Array[Row], ages: Array[Row]) {
    // do some processing
}
```

I've tried broadcasting the distinctSites across all nodes, but this did not prove fruitful.

This seems such a simple concept and yet I have spent a couple of days looking into this. I'm very new to Scala/Spark, so apologies if this is a ridiculous question!

Any suggestions or tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD API provides a number of functions which can be used to perform operations in groups starting with low level repartition / repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions and ending with a number of *byKey methods (combineByKey, groupByKey, reduceByKey, etc.).

Example :

```
rdd.map( tup => ((tup._1, tup._2, tup._3), tup) ).
  groupByKey().
  forEachPartition( iter => doSomeJob(iter) )
```

In DataFrame you can use aggregate functions,GroupedData class provides a number of methods for the most common functions, including count, max, min, mean and sum

Example :

```
   val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      (1, 10.3, 10), (1, 11.5, 10),
      (2, 12.6, 20), (3, 2.6, 30))
    ).toDF("Site_ID ", "Time ", "Age")

df.show()

+--------+-----+---+
|Site_ID |Time |Age|
+--------+-----+---+
|       1| 10.3| 10|
|       1| 11.5| 10|
|       2| 12.6| 20|
|       3|  2.6| 30|
+--------+-----+---+


    df.groupBy($"Site_ID ").count.show

+--------+-----+
|Site_ID |count|
+--------+-----+
|       1|    2|
|       3|    1|
|       2|    1|
+--------+-----+
```

Note : As you have mentioned that solution is very slow ,You need to use partition ,in your case range partition is good option.

- http://dev.sortable.com/spark-repartition/
- https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-partitions.html
- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/

Comment: Thank you! It was the groupByKey() that got me to the place I needed. Greatly appreciated, and thank you for your speedy reply too.